# Connecting to a Postgresql database running on host OS

Tags: postgresql

i am running a postgresql instance in my host machine (Mac OS). I am able to access this instance by JDBC using localhost property in my Spring Boot application

Now i have a guest Ubuntu Virtual Box OS installed. and i want to install the same instance from this OS.

So i just changed the data source url of the same application from localhost to the host ip and port . 
But now when i deploy the application and try to run it, i get "connection refused" error.

Telnet to host os from guest OS (10.0.2.2 5432) is working fine.

Content from my pg_hba.conf file

```
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                md5
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

Connections and authentications content from my postgresql.conf

```
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'              # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'   # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)
```

So i have configured my postgrsql instance to accept connections from any IP.

i am behind a firewall.

Probably i am still missing somethings

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with my configuration of Spring Boot and Cloud Foundry..it was nowhere related to Postgresql.

Curious readers please head over to [No unique service maching interface error in Spring Boot Cloud Foundry error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418856/no-unique-service-maching-interface-error-in-spring-boot-cloud-foundry-error) for the solution